# Why can't Donald Trump revoke birthright citizenship?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, immigration

Recently, there has been a huge debate about revoking birthright citizenship from children born in the US to illegal alien immigrants. I read [here](https://www.politico.com/story/2018/10/30/trump-birthright-citizenship-plan-900891) that almost all left and right wings of the US political system will likely oppose this revoking birthright citizenship idea. Still, it's not clear to me that: is there anything to fundamentally prevent Trump's administration from revoking birthright citizenship, such as something in the US Constitution, or politicians just not helping Trump to do so because of the recent US political atmosphere? I will be very grateful if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: The link in your question mentions in its second sentence that this _is_ covered in the US Constitution.  I don't see any question here that isn't already covered in your linked article, and others on the subject.  There are some who debate the commonly held interpretation of that sentence of the constitution, but that is not the same as asserting it is nowhere in the constitution.

Comment: Relevant question on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33056/what-is-the-meaning-of-and-subject-to-the-jurisdiction-thereof-in-the-14th-ame)

Comment: It is against the 14th amendment of the United States constitution . I am not sure amending this would work . Perhaps something like what other countries do which is in order to report a birth in the country, the parents must be legally in the country.

Comment: @Matt the reasoning you outline usually overlooks the fact that a child cannot petition for a parent's immigration until the child's 21st birthday.  Anyone who understands this and gives birth in the US for the purpose of obtaining US citizenship for her child is thinking more about the interests of her child than about claiming citizenship for herself or other family members.

Comment: @phoog Fair point, I'm sure there are some people that have a 21-year vision, and more people that don't. It still provides incentive for people to illegally enter the country, if at least to provide a better future for their child - a noble thing, but an illegal thing. I'm not defending or opposing this - just ensuring that OP has the facts to think for him/herself

Comment: Mary Anne McLeod sounds pretty much like a Scottish name, not an US american one. Would be a funny move of this alien's child to revoke his own birthright.

Comment: @Damon she naturalized in 1942, four years before Trump was born.  It still rather smacks of hypocrisy, though, as two of his three wives have also been immigrants (with at least one having had questions raised about her immigration status during her early time in the US).  But this isn't exceptional; he hasn't had much to say about his parents in law having become US citizens through the very "chain migration" route he so loves to rail against.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

[14th Amendment to the US Constitution, Section 1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/amendmentxiv):

> All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States and of the state wherein they reside. No state shall make or enforce any law which shall abridge the privileges or immunities of citizens of the United States; nor shall any state deprive any person of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law; nor deny to any person within its jurisdiction the equal protection of the laws.

Amendments *amend* the U.S. Constitution, so they are a part of the Constitution. Only further amendments can alter the language of other amendments, as seen by the passage of [18th Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eighteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) and subsequent repeal by [21st Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-first_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution). Most argue that, in order to revoke birthright citizenship, you would need to go through the [process of amending the Constitution](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/constitution), which doesn't involve the President at all.

Some in the U.S. try to make the argument based on the phrase *"subject to the jurisdiction thereof"*, and argue that people born in the United States to non-citizen parents aren't "subject to U.S. jurisdiction." Whether that's a valid legal argument is a bit out of scope for this site, but at least one question about it has been asked at [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33056/what-is-the-meaning-of-and-subject-to-the-jurisdiction-thereof-in-the-14th-ame).

Comment: I've done voted this answer because there isn't a stated intention from trump to amend the constitution that its an EO, but to affect the interpretation.

Comment: @DrunkCynic My intention here is to answer the question asked. If you want to see a different answer to a different question about _Trump's intentions_, I'd suggest asking it so long as you aren't asking anyone to read his mind.

Comment: @JeffLambert The question doesn't ask about amending the constitution, just curtailing birthright citizenship.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Yes, birthright citizenship that has constitutional backing settled in existing case law. The answer as to "why can't he" is because "he would need to amend the Constitution" coupled with "he can't do that." If his _intention_ is to try to create new case law, or if his _intention_ is to simply rally his base before the midterms, only time can tell.

Comment: If you read the article the OP linked, the Supreme Court has defined those who aren't "subject to the jurisdiction thereof": the children of foreign diplomats, or of foreign forces occupying part of the country.  Undocumented immigrants clearly are subject to the jurisdiction of the US, as they can be arrested & tried for crimes, exactly as citizens are.

Comment: Is the US v. Wong Kim appropriate here?  I will admit that the legality of the Executive order will be argued but it is far from settled law. The flaw of US v. Wong Kim is that his parents were not illegal aliens, they were legal residents, this is different, but again, I am not on the court so that remains an opinion, just like the applicability of US v. Wong is also an opinion. We have a bunch of opinions but no surety. This answer is still wrong because no one knows if it is unconstitutional at this time and saying so does not make it a fact

Comment: @FrankCedeno Wonk Kim Ark can be distinguished from the present case by the status of the parents, but other cases such as Plyler v. Doe suggest that illegal aliens are in fact "subject to the jurisdiction" of the US for the purpose of the citizenship clause, so the distinction is without effect.  After all, an illegal alien who commits a crime can be prosecuted. The same is not true of a diplomat or a diplomat's family members.  See my [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/33059/333) at [Law.SE].

Comment: @jamesqf That would be the farcical side effect of such an EO: If they aren't subject to our jurisdiction, they can't be deported because they *aren't subject to our laws*

Comment: @phoog, You provide a compelling argument, however the phrasing of the equal protection clause and the naturalization clause is different. The EPC reads "within its jurisdiction" while the NC clause reads "subject to its jurisdiction".  I will not say your argument is not compelling, it may well win in court but still, it can be argued that prior case law does not apply. Anyway, it will never be argued that way, I will bet it will be argued that Trump is too racist

Comment: @FrankCedeno the difference in phrasing between the equal protection and citizenship clauses is in fact why I said "suggest" rather than using a stronger word.  But I doubt any lawyer would use the racism argument because it's just too tenuous.  The religious discrimination argument against the travel ban had a far more substantial basis, but it wasn't all that successful in the end.

Comment: @phoog, I'm not saying this to be hyperbolic, I just think it is interesting, while the anti travel ban argument was about religion, the current times make it more likely that the racism argument will be at the top of minds judging from the media headlines. My interest is a sporting one, not trying to make a statement. Anyone interested in a betting pool?

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Short and to the point but nevertheless quite complete.

Comment: I like this answer, but it is missing a couple of possibilities: 1) The Constitution is interpreted by SCOTUS. This is a body that has been drastically rebalanced recently, including two members who owe their position to this president. Its possible (one hopes unlikely, but possible) they could decide to reinterpret the 14th in a way amenable to the Administration. 2) Enforcement of SCOTUS decisions is left to the Executive branch of whatever body they affect. Its quite possible this president could decide to pull an Andrew Jackson, and refuse to abide by a court decision against him.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - Since birthright citizenship is in the Constitution, curtailing it would require amending the Constitution. But you know this.

Comment: @FrankCedeno - If you read the opinions on that ruling, it's very clear that they only see very specific exceptions, which they explicitly list. "Illegal alien" was not on that list, and certainly illegal aliens are subject to our jurisdiction, otherwise we would not be able to arrest or deport them. That ruling is very clear an applicable to this current claim.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Birthright citizenship isn't in the constitution. US v Wong Kim Ark was scoped to the children legal residents who were affected by the Chinese Exclusion Act. Through their compliance with immigration law, they would be considered subject to us Jurisdiction. Illegal immigrants are not in compliance with US immigration law, thus are not residents and subject to us jurisdiction as described by the 14th convention. This is why illegal immigrants must be informed of their right to seek legal aid from their Consulate when arrested for a crime?

Comment: @DrunkCynic - No, it was not scoped in that regard, which I actually already covered in my previous comment.  The opinion put forward specifically delineated that there were only a few exceptions to birthright citizenship, and put absolutely zero consideration to the legal status of the parents. In fact, it pretty much went the other direction and made it a point to show that the legal status of the parents was largely immaterial to this. There was nothing in the language of the opinion to suggest this was narrow in that way.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - Since the 14th Amendment is part of the Constitution, and it specifically spells it out, your claim that it's not there seem fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Doesn't this conflict with children of diplomats not receiving US citizenship upon birth? Diplomats are subject to US jurisdiction, despite limitations set out in the Vienna Convention.

Comment: @JonathanReez [USCIS disagrees](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/Print/PolicyManual-Volume7-PartO-Chapter3.html) that diplomats are subject to US jurisdiction. Also see [8 CFR 101.3(a)(1)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?&node=se8.1.101_13).

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, there is no equality between jurisdiction and being able to arrest or deport.  They are not the same thing.  As the writer of the amendment stated in his own words and common sense will tell you, jurisdiction means the relationship between the government and the person, not law enforcement and the person.  The argument for anchor babies is the equal protections clause, not the non-sense of there is jurisdiction because law enforcement can arrest and deport. If you follow that argument than the entire world is within the jurisdiction of the US (extradition treaties)

Comment: @FrankCedeno I'm sorry, but I'm skeptical that you can separate the relationship between "government and the person" and "law enforcement and the person," they are one and the same. Law enforcement is a part of the government. Any restriction on government action also applies to law enforcement.

Comment: @DrunkCynic *every* alien is entitled to consular aid when arrested, including tourists, nonimmigrant workers, and green card holders.  All of those people are subject to the jurisdiction of the US, as are illegal aliens.  If they weren't subject to the jurisdiction of the US, it would not be lawful for the US to arrest them.  That is the case with diplomats, and, significantly, their children, who are indeed immune from arrest.

Comment: @FrankCedeno being in a different jurisdiction with which the US has an extradition treaty is not the same as being subject to US jurisdiction.  The US cannot in fact arrest such a person; they have to arrange for the person to be arrested by the other jurisdiction. There also has to be a formal hearing in the other jurisdiction's judicial system before the other jurisdiction will release the person into the custody of the US.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - You do understand that law enforcement is a function of government, and derives its powers from government, right?  This is a totally imaginary separation that you are inventing here. There is no way that law enforcement has the ability to do anything to anyone unless government has jurisdiction over them. Anyone within the United States is subject to our laws.  ***THAT*** is jurisdiction. If they are not subject to our jurisdiction, we have no standing to request or demand that they do anything. The argument for "anchor babies" is that the Fourteenth says they are citizens.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/jurisdiction

Comment: @phoog, tell that to Manuel Noriega

Comment: @FrankCedeno Manuel Noriega surrendered to the _military_ and was detained as a _prisoner of war_. Please keep comments on topic.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I disinclined to continue this debate with you in comments, given the differences in how we interpret the facts at hand. We fundamentally disagree on the intentions of the 14th Amendment, the applicability of the US v WKA decision, and every other factor.

Comment: @TemporalWolf, it would be, but the opposite is rather true: almost the _only_ thing that can be done to a diplomat is deportation. Likewise with migrants if they were excluded from the jurisdiction.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - Fair enough, but I'd suggest you examine what that disagreement is based upon, because one one side you have pretty much every legal, historical and Constitutional scholar, as well as the very clear and specific language of the only SCOTUS rulings, and on the other side you have people pushing a partisan agenda, and wishful thinking on their part. On one side, all you have to do is follow the clear language through history, and on the other you have to twist yourself into pretzels to arrive at a "maybe" situation. Have a good day.

Comment: @Zeus They would absolutely not be diplomats. Diplomatic law is very specific and in the US requires registration. Actually, the result would likely instead be them falling into the same category as an invading enemy force and afforded none of the protections of the constitution.

Comment: @TemporalWolf why wouldn't invading enemies be protected by the constitution?  They fall under military law, which is subject to review by the judiciary branch, and they enjoy, for example, a right to due process.  An *occupying* force is exempt from the entire jurisdiction of the US, but that is more of a practical matter, because they have by force prevented the US from exercising its jurisdiction.  After the end of the occupation, though, if they come into US custody they are subject to constitutional protections.

Answer (score 46):

A President can revoke birthright citizenship, it's just that the revocation would likely be immediately challenged by courts, and potentially never enforced if it's found to be unconstitutional.

---

Technically, a US President has the authority to direct a federal official or agency to enforce the law in any way they choose through what are called [executive orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_order). According to the [American Bar Association](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/public_education/resources/teacher_portal/educational_resources/executive_orders/):

> Executive orders are issued by the President of the United States, acting in his capacity as head of the executive branch, directing a federal official or administrative agency to engage in a course of action or refrain from a course of action. They are enforceable to the extent that they represent a valid exercise of the President’s power (i.e. the action must be within the president’s constitutional authority).

However, as explained in that last line US Presidents cannot actually order the federal government to enforce their executive orders if they exceed the authority granted to the President by the constitution. Part of a President's responsibility as president is adhering to the [US Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Constitution), and the Constitution makes it clear in [the 14th amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Text) that any person born in the US must be given citizenship:

> All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States and of the State wherein they reside.

So, if President Trump wrote an executive order that told the federal government not to give citizenship at birth, he may not have the ability to actually enforce it due to it potentially going against the Constitution. If he orders it but it is found unconstitutional, it could be struck down by courts and/or Congress could simply refuse to provide the funding necessary to carry out enforcement.

---

An alternative method to enforce this new citizenship law is through [amending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_amendment#United_States_of_America) the Constitution itself to override the 14th amendment. However, such an amendment is not directly within a President's power: it would first have to be [proposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Five_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Proposing_amendments) by either a 2/3 majority of both houses of Congress or by Congress calling a convention of state legislatures, and then [ratified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Five_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Ratification_of_amendments) by a 3/4 majority of state legislatures. This is not likely to happen anytime soon.

---

**Addendum:** Thanks to some comments by DrunkCynic, we have a court case that offers precedent to who the 14th amendment covers and how an attempt to reinterpret the citizen-by-birth section may be seen by courts.

The (very brief) background of this case is that for a time the [US prohibited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Exclusion_Act) the immigration of Chinese laborers. A man named Wong Kim Ark was born in the US to Chinese nationals who were living in California at the time, and he lived most of his life in the US. Upon returning to the US from a trip to China he was denied permission to enter the US on the grounds that he was considered a Chinese immigrant rather than a US citizen.

He argued that he was in fact a US citizen, and the issue was resolved in the Supreme Court case [United States v. Wong Kim Ark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Wong_Kim_Ark). According to [this Cornell law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/169/649) summary of the 6-2 decision by the Supreme Court, it was ruled that he definitely was a US citizen and thus exempt from the prohibition on Chinese immigration:

> A child born in the United States, of parents of Chinese descent, who, at the time of his birth, are subjects of the Emperor of China, but have a permanent domicil and residence in the United States, and are there carrying on business, and are not employed in any diplomatic or official capacity under the Emperor of China, becomes at the time of his birth a citizen of the United States, by virtue of the first clause of the Fourteenth Amendment of the Constitution...

In short, one could argue that this case upholds the idea that the 14th amendment applies to *any* person born in the US, even if born to non-US citizens. However, one could also argue that this case only applies to Wong Kim Ark's specific situation of being born to non-US citizens who were legal permanent residents at the time, and that the 14th amendment doesn't actually apply to children born to illegal immigrants.

So, any argument on whether or not a President can end birthright citizenship likely falls, at least in part, on the interpretation of this and related cases during any court challenge in the event that this ever happens.

Comment: My prediction, based on past orders, It will not be challenged as unconstitutional but will be held while the court finds if it is racially motivated.

Comment: I've done voted this answer because it doesn't dive past a surface reading of the fourteenth Amendment.

Comment: @DrunkCynic You pretty much down voted all the answers.. May I ask you to elaborate your idea about this question in an answer?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I upvoted tj1000's answer, and recommended an audition, because it covers every point I would make.

Comment: @FrankCedeno it doesn't matter whether it's racially motivated because it directly contradicts the constitution.  It would go to court as soon as someone born in the US were placed in deportation hearings or denied a passport, whereupon it would be promptly ruled unconstitutional without regard to anyone's race.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic: Answers don't HAVE to dive past the 14th Amendment.  That's the full, complete, entire answer.

Comment: @DrunkCynic That's twice now that you've said that you've "done voted" a question, and not given any explanation. The first time, it was plausibly a typo, but now I'm wondering whether you actually don't know how to spell "down", or whether you actually are posting while drunk. Do you have a coherent explanation for why you've downvoted this answer, and could you post a clear explanation under the other answer why you've downvoted it?

Comment: @Acccumulation copy and paste has a way of amplifying typos such that repeated misspellings are less compelling evidence in opposition to a hypothesis of careless typing than they otherwise would be.

Comment: @DrunkCynic the question *explicitly suggests* that a constitutional definition of citizenship would be a sufficient answer ("[is there] anything to fundamentally prevent Trump's administration from revoking birthright citizenship, **such as something in the US Constitution** [?]" -- emphasis added).

Comment: @Acccumulation  not intoxicated, at work on a mobile phone that auto corrected down to done. Odd that. The reasons I've downvoted the answers are in the comments. No copy pasta here.

Comment: @DrunkCynic You said that the answer doesn't "dive past a surface reading of the fourteenth Amendment", but don't provide any explanation as to in what way that is so, or why it invalidates the answer. Comments are for improving an answer. Just saying "There is some factor you haven't taken into account", without saying what that is, is a poor way of inducing improvement.

Comment: @jamesqf Not when there is an existing SCOTUS decision that examines the Amendment at issue: see US v Wong Kim Ark

Comment: @Acccumulation Okay: this answer does not account for the decision and scope of US v Wong Kim Ark, the arguments during the ratification of the 14th Amendment, or the meaning of "subject to the jurisdiction of," when it was ratified.

Comment: @DrunkCynic: Added that Wong Kim Ark case into my answer which brief explanations of potential interpretations by either side, thanks for the example. Anything more thorough might be better for Law though.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic: Yes, and if you bother to read the Wong Kim Ark decision, you see that it absolutely upholds the straightforward reading of the 14th Amendment: https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/169/649

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, in the case of his parents that had an established household and we're resident aliens of the United States.  That is the scope of US v WKA. Are illegal immigrants residents in accordance with immigration law?

Comment: @DrunkCynic it doesn't matter whether they're residents.  What matters is whether they are subject to the jurisdiction of the US, *and they are.*  See my [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/33059/333) at [Law.SE].

Comment: @jamesqf: It's not quite a straightforward reading, the exact wording is closer to "these legal residents were definitely under US jurisdiction and in the US, so their kid is a US citizen". The fact that the parents were legal residents is directly mentioned in the decision, so although it doesn't seem like that was a core reason for the decision someone could try to argue that the decision only applies when the parents are legal residents.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic: There was no such thing as an illegal resident back then.  However, the language of the 14th Amendment is perfectly clear.  As is the Supreme Court decision (at least as far as any legal document is ever clear).  It includes everyone except the 3 specific exceptions: Diplomats, occupying powers, and Indians not taxed.  (And there probably aren't any of the latter left these days.)  Likewise, resident has a perfectly clear meaning, which includes most if not all immigrants, legal or not.

Comment: @jamesqf Or it doesn't include "foreigners, aliens, who belong to the families of ambassadors, or foreign ministers accredited to the government of the United States." The major cause of ambiguity is the mere lack of an oxford comma.

Comment: @DrunkCynic what oxford comma do you think is lacking?  There *is* a comma before "who belong to the families," but there is no conjunction.  This further supports my belief that "who..." is a relative clause describing and restricting the "foreigners, aliens" whom the amendment excludes.  For why mention diplomats at all if the exclusion covers all foreigners?  Furthermore, Howard did not challenge other assertions that the amendment would grant US citizenship to US-born children of foreigners, which he surely would have done if he thought those assertions incorrect.

Comment: Don't worry about criticisms about "surface reading," some want people to see a fantasy scenario that does not exist. "Subject to jurisdiction" - the only people in the US who are not subject to our jurisdiction are those with diplomatic immunity. Otherwise, anyone here is subject to our laws. That clause is only meant to make sure that people who are part of a diplomatic mission who give birth in an embassy are excluded from this.  I'd like to know where you get the claim that the President has the power to revoke citizenship for natural-born citizens, though.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic: There's no ambiguity whatever.  If you read that as "foreigners" being foreigners in general, and not diplomats &c, then it would exclude Wong Kim Ark from being a citizen.  But since the decision held that he WAS a citizen, that reading is obviously wrong.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: It's a legitimate concern, because I could definitely see the attempt to enact it this go like: exec. order -> challenged based on precedence -> "no, that precedence only applies to legal residents" -> another Supreme Court decision. As for why he has the power: the President has the power to direct the federal government to enforce laws in any way via executive orders, but those orders are subject to judicial review and can be pretty easily halted by courts(like those travel bans last year). So, the revocation would be fully enforceable law until it's (immediately) challenged.

Comment: @jamesqf in the case of WKA, his parents were legal immigrants, though denied nationalization, and would be considered permanent aliens. https://www.loc.gov/teachers/classroommaterials/presentationsandactivities/presentations/immigration/chinese6.html

Comment: But your analysis relies on the president's being required to "give citizenship" to people and an order "not to give citizenship."  That is not correct; citizenship is given by automatic operation of law (constitutional or statutory).  What the president *can* do is try to assert a new interpretation of the law, but only inasmuch as it affects acts the president has authority over, such as issuing passports or initiating legal actions against someone, such as deportation proceedings, that depend on the person not being a US citizen.

Comment: @Giter - I'm looking for anything, anywhere, that claims the President has the power to revoke actual citizenship, which is what that looks like. Challenging the legitimacy of the citizenship is a weak argument, but you're also claiming that he has the power to revoke citizenship, which I'm not aware exists, anywhere, for natural-born citizenship. "A President can revoke birthright citizenship" - no, there's nothing, anywhere, that says he can.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: I meant "Trump's administration arguing the prior court case about kids of legal residents don't apply to this situation" was a legitimate concern, not that illegal immigrants might be considered outside of US jurisdiction(otherwise it's paradoxically impossible for them to be illegal at all). *I* believe that the Supreme court would probably would uphold the exact same ruling as those prior cases, it's just that there's a possible (and *extremely* tenuous) argument that could be made to prevent the revocation from just being immediately overturned without a new court case.

Comment: It's not a legitimate concern, because that court case was very clear in its opinion that there were only a couple kinds of exceptions, so it did not rule that "because they are legally here, though not citizens," it ruled that (paraphrasing) "there are only a couple exceptions to birthright citizenship (Native American sovereignty, diplomatic circumstances and invading armies) and this does not fall under those exceptions." By explicitly stating what the only exceptions were, they made it clear about these circumstances.

Comment: FYI - check with me on November 7 and beyond. This is merely bluster to put a red-meat issue for his base on the front-burner, and try to push Healthcare to the background as a motivating issue for voters. Even he knows this is nonsense, and will probably claim he never said it after mid-term elections are over.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: Oh yeah, this and other things he's been saying at his rallies are (thankfully) just a stunt.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85206/discussion-on-answer-by-giter-why-cant-donald-trump-revoke-birthright-citizensh).

Comment: Another case of interest is Elk v. Wilkins, though that one is a bit unique because of the unique status of Native Americans and reservations in the US.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic: No, his parents were not legal immigrants, or illegal, because at that time there was no such thing.

Comment: Year(s) in the "Addendum" section would be helpful.

Answer (score 11):

The legal argument focuses on this part:

> and subject to the jurisdiction thereof

Trump may take the approach of an executive order that declares people who did not enter the country legally are not subject to the jurisdiction of the US. That won't be applied retroactively to existing anchor babies, but it will exclude any future such occurrences.

Whether that argument will pass the supreme court or not, remains to be seen.

It should be noted that most European countries limit birthright citizenship only to children of legal immigrants or legal visitors. While their example doesn't directly apply to interpretation of the US constitution, it does show that this interpretation is not without long standing precedent. That may be a factor in a court judgment, as 'common law', or commonly accepted practices among democracies, is occasionally cited in legal arguments where the written law (or constitution) isn't entirely clear.

Comment: Common Law will only port other common law rulings.  For example, most nations with Common Law systems have the same rules for negligence, which come from a ruling that originated in Scotland.  But, the U.S. does not use Common Law standing from other countries all the time, as they must comply with the Constitution (i.e. Defamation in the U.S. is vastly different than any other common law systems).  International Porting is allowable but not mandatory.  Continental Europe would not ordinarily get ported as the use Civil Law systems.

Comment: You answer is important as it is the only one so far that includes the basis of the argument for the executive order. It would be more complete if you added 8 US Code 1401 which repeats the "Subject to the Jurisdiction thereof" as the true intent of the 14th amendment. Further the 14th amendment is tied to give newly freed slaves all the rights of citizenship and, as the author of the amendment Sen. Jacob Howard said, "...will not of course include persons born in the United States who are foreigners, aliens, who belong to the families of ambassadors or foreign ministers"

Comment: @FrankCedeno Any reference for: "Sen. Jacob Howard said, "...will not of course include persons born in the United States who are foreigners, aliens, who belong to the families of ambassadors or foreign ministers""?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer http://memory.loc.gov/cgi-bin/ampage?collId=llcg&fileName=073/llcg073.db&recNum=11  reference for quote

Comment: @hszmv "Common Law will only port other common law rulings." This isn't true, as you go on to say and show yourself. You refer to _Donoghue v Stevenson,_ but Scotland isn't really a proper common law jurisdiction... so not exactly a great example to illustrate your point to begin with. And in Europe now, through the auspices of the ECJ and the ECHR as well as in national courts, decisions with an origin in one system (common or civil) travel to the other routinely; civil and common law are not as resolutely never-the-twain-may-meet divorced as they once were.

Comment: You've got the better portion of an any answer I'd add, so I'll just recommend the following. A rebuttal to Trumps action will like reference US v Wong Kim Ark, a SCOTUS case about the citizenship of the son born to Chinese migrants during the Chinese exclusion act. The response is to refer to the final paragraph of the decision, where it references his parents "domicil and residency." In the case of illegal immigrants, they don't have a condition of residency in the us, because they've bypassed immigration law.

Comment: It may just be me, but if you say someone isn't subject to the jurisdiction of the US, wouldn't that mean you couldn't arrest them, try them, and kick them out?  I feel like that's the opposite of the intended result.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explain how Trump argues people in the US illegally aren't subject to our jurisdiction.

Comment: @AzorAhai Trump hasn't made that argument yet, and we aren't privy to the advice of his council.

Comment: @Bobson Differing understanding of the word jurisdiction. Visitors are still subject to laws, but are they considered residents of the nation ?

Comment: @DrunkCynic: "but are they considered residents of the nation ?" - What does that have to do with jurisdiction? If I am travelling through a city or state that I am not a resident of, and commit murder there, I am under the jurisdiction of that city or state. What definition of jurisdiction are you using that is equivalent to residency?

Comment: @DrunkCynic It seems you want to prosecute visitors or foreigners or whatever alien people under the "nation" laws but you are saying they are not under the US jurisdiction, which seems to me like a double interpretation of law whenever it is aligned to your interests...

Comment: "that won't be applied retroactively" do you have any evidence to support that claim?

Comment: In the land and not "subject to the jurisdiction thereof" is not a situation any nation would create deliberately unless they want people to literally get away with murder.

Comment: @FrankCedeno,  "...will not of course include persons born in the United States who are foreigners, aliens, who belong to the families of ambassadors or foreign ministers" - because ambassadors and foreign ministers aren't subject to the jurisdiction of the US, i.e. diplomatic immunity. As Bobson noted, those who enter the country illegally are indeed subject to our laws and can be imprisoned before being deported. I suppose we'll all just have to wait and see how it all turns out...

Comment: @FrankCedeno the Howard quote looks like a confusion of punctuation.  It is transcribed speech, after all.  It seems that he intended to say that the amendment doesn't apply to those foreigners and aliens who belong to the families of ambassadors or foreign ministers (rather than that it doesn't apply to foreigners and aliens in addition to the families of ambassadors etc.). This makes sense in context, which is discussion of whether to exclude "Indians not taxed." The conclusion was that this was unnecessary because they are already, like ambassadors, not subject to US jurisdiction.

Comment: @Joshua but exactly that situation exists for diplomats, who literally can (and sometimes do) get away with murder if the sending state refuses to waive immunity.

Comment: @Joshua: There is a common situation where people are in the land (any country, not just the US) but not subject to its jurisdiction: diplomats.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_immunity

Comment: @phoog You need to go deeper into the quoted material for the back and forth with a Californian congressman that greater expands on Howard's reasoning. Damn the lack of an Oxford comma.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I read the whole thing and I didn't see anything inconsistent with my interpretation.  Can you describe what you're talking about or where it is?

Comment: @jamesqf that isn't the meaning of jurisdiction as used in the fourteenth Amendment and affirmative decision in US v Wong Kim Ark.

Comment: @DrunkCynic "that isn't the meaning of jurisdiction": which of jamesqf's comments are you referring to? Wong Kim Ark mentions the diplomatic immunity exception repeatedly and at length, so I can't imagine that you're responding to the comment about the diplomatic immunity exception.

Comment: @phoog I did, and I think the jurisprudence disproves your position.

Comment: @DrunkCynic what does the jurisprudence prove, and how? What *is* the meaning of jurisdiction in the 14th? Are you saying that diplomats' US-born children *are* citizens of the US?

Comment: "and subject to the jurisdiction thereof" < This statement focuses on the persons being born in the USA - it is not related to their parents. AND once you are in the USA (and this applies to almost every country) you are subject to its jurisdiction: if you commit a crime, you will be jailed or executed there (exclusion: if somehow special diplomatic relationships exist, like embassies and so). So yes: they will need another amend to make Trump's order constitutional.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85204/discussion-on-answer-by-tj1000-why-cant-donald-trump-revoke-birthright-citizens).

Comment: @Bobson " if you say someone isn't subject to the jurisdiction of the US, wouldn't that mean you couldn't arrest them, try them, and kick them out?" Or alternatively, you might argue that you can do anything you like to them without regard to any US law, and their only redress would be to get the perpetrator extradited for trial in their own country (and the US could easily concoct reasons to refuse the extradition, no doubt)

Comment: Why would you assume that Trump's hypothetical executive order does not retroactively strip the citizenship of existing people?  Based on past behavior, the natural assumption is that it will be implemented in the most cruel way possible:  some people are going to be challenged when they attempt to return to the US, their passports will be confiscated, they will be pressured to sign papers revoking their citizenship, and they will be put on a plane back to where they came.  Some of them will have citizen parents but will be unable to prove it and thus get bum rushed.

Comment: @emory If the children of immigrants could be stripped of their citizenship retroactively, they would then supposedly be deported to the home of (one of) their parents. Could this apply to Trump himself? Would Scotland be obliged to take him? What if the UK said No?

Comment: @RedSonja the cruelest option would be to simply deny them re-entry back to the US.  This would never be exercised against Trump, but a hypothetical child of a Scottish person might decide to visit the extended family on a 30 day tourist visa.  During those 30 days, their passport might be revoked.  They will not be able to return to the US.  They will have trouble travelling to 3rd countries.  Extending their UK visa will be their problem.

Answer (score 5):

I found the [argument put forth here](https://www.nationalreview.com/corner/donald-trump-end-birthright-citizenship-by-executive-order/) to be quite compelling

> Again, there are reports that the president may issue such an order. The problem as I see it is twofold. First, the legal landscape is not limited to the 14th Amendment. Congress has enacted a statute, [Section 1401](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1401) of the immigration and naturalization laws (Title 8, U.S. Code). In pertinent part, it appears merely to codify in statutory law what the 14th Amendment says: included among U.S. citizens is any “person born in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof.” But that means the issue is not just what jurisdiction was understood to mean in 1868 when the 14th Amendment was adopted, but what it meant in 1952, when the statute defining U.S. citizenship was enacted (it has been amended several times since then).
>
> Secondly, even assuming the meaning was the same, Congress’s codification of the 14th Amendment — which it did not need to do — is a strong expression of Congress’s intent to exercise its constitutional authority to set the terms of citizenship.

His point here (elaborated in the article) is that Congress has put forth a strong hint that they wanted birthright citizenship and that they wanted it as recently as 1952. It seems unlikely that any court is simply going to upend the apple cart and throw out an interpretation of a Constitutional amendment that Congress itself wrote into law just for good measure. As such, Congress would need to pass a law to change the meaning. Such a change is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Tim Pool did a segment that discussed various angles of this discussion that haven't been discussed here yet:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wm-zDtdQzN4

The short version (as has been discussed by other answers) is that he can end it, but the courts will almost certainly overturn it.

Some details that haven't been mentioned yet is that the meta discussions during the original drafting of the amendment specifically said that, of course the amendment wouldn't include children of diplomats or foreigners.  This was, however, one comment amid what I can imagine is many.  It may not represent the final interpretation of the language adopted by the Congress at the time.

So one point for the Constitution not supporting birthright citizenship.  Which may not be an actual point depending on what further literature was generated during the Congress.

Subsequent case law, however, has set up ample legislative precedent for the idea that birthright citizenship excludes only those who are formally outside of the US jurisdiction -- i.e., diplomats.  This case law has been discussed quite a bit in other answers.

So lots of points for numerous duly appointed judges and duly elected legislative bodies supporting birthright citizenship.

In the end, the only thing indicating that the Constitution doesn't grant birthright citizenship (so far as I've seen) is a comment by one of the drafters of the amendment.  Everything else points the other direction.

Comment: I've seen references to meta discussions concerning diplomats, but none concerning illegal foreigners (in fact, the state of immigration law in the 19th century was such that the idea of an illegal foreigner was perhaps not much considered).

Comment: @phoog You are correct -- the comment was of foreigners in general, not illegal foreigners.  My browser was acting up at the time so I couldn't reference the source material to confirm.

Comment: I disagree: I believe the comment is confusing, but it was intended to denote children of diplomats and ministers.  Others made comments about US-born children of foreigners being made US citizens by the amendment, and Howard did not challenge those comments.  So "who belong..." is a relative clause *describing* the "foreigners, aliens" to which the amendment's exclusion applies, not an additional list item.  Considering it as an additional list item leads to absurdities of interpretation, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

In our constitutional republic, the President, and in fact any elected official, doesn't get to decide *post-facto* who is a citizen and who isn't.  It isn't a difficult concept.

The text of the 14th Amendment says what it says, and the literal interpretation is what it is; and that literal interpretation has never been meaningfully questioned, until very recently.

If the President did, in fact, declare that a specific person's citizenship was null and void, perhaps via a tweet, even then, **nothing would happen**.  Locally-elected law enforcement and district attorneys, who are responsible for the vast majority of arrests and prosecutions, would openly scoff at such an edict; but they don't have to report immigration offenses anyway.  The courts, the state and local bureaucracies (such as the election office, the motor-vehicles department, public school districts and university systems, welfare offices) would continue to honor that unfortunate person's documents as normal.  One's Social Security card, driver's license or photo ID, student ID, MediCare card, etc.

The private sector would continue to likewise process that person's documents, like normal.  He or she could open a bank account, or interview and accept an offer of employment.  Federal law enforcement, who arrest and prosecute people in federal court for a living, would continue to abide by the law; they have to.  The only question is whether the secretive, black-helicopter types under the President's own formal authority would bend to the obvious, long-standing legal and procedural norms; and they very absolutely will, sooner or later.

The political and administrative bodies of government cannot take away citizenship.  Even the courts, when rendering verdicts, are highly reluctant to treat citizens as non-citizens, under any circumstance -- including when one is guilty of treason.  They can execute or incarcerate a citizen just as well as a foreigner, and they don't need to indulge the notion that a citizen is a non-citizen in order to perform their constitutional function.

Comment: Do you have sources to support (some of) the statements in your answer? If you do, please add them as that would make your answer a lot better.

Comment: Here is an example of local LEAs scoffing: https://www.cato.org/blog/california-trust-act-reduced-deportations

Comment: That having been said, that is more an example of mandated scoffing, as per state legislation.  I was thinking more along the lines of more local, spontaneous non-cooperation, due to local electoral realities, and the batstuffing-insanity of the proposal in question.

Comment: If you want to know how career federal LEAs generally think of that insanity and its source, just read through James Comey's twitter feed and draw your own conclusions.

Comment: Yea, I can imagine that being true for some lEOs in some states, but I can also see the opposite being true in other states. This week's Last Week Tonight with John Oliver actually showed both sides with regard to the election of states attorneys general and it shows that local judicial official can be very partisan as well.

Comment: maybe that's outside the scope of this question.  You can't revoke national citizenship if that revocation isn't honored nation-wide.

Comment: I just mean that if the national policy is there, then there will be local enforcement officers willing to execute that policy. Maybe some states will resist, but others will go along.

Comment: "that literal interpretation has never been meaningfully questioned, until very recently." This is simply not correct. Even in the U.S. v. Wong Kim Ark case mentioned in another answer, this position was very much [questioned by 2 justices of the Supreme Court of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Wong_Kim_Ark#Dissent). Of course, they weren't arguing that the amendment shouldn't be read literally, but rather there is - and long has been - dispute over the intended literal meaning of "subject to the jurisdiction thereof."

Comment: @Ibrahim The opinion of law enforcement officers is irrelevant. LEOs are (usually) not legal scholars, nor do they have any power to change or interpret the law.

Comment: "In our constitutional republic, the President, and in fact any elected official, doesn't get to decide post-facto who is a citizen and who isn't." Of course they can. Amending the Constitution is indisputably one way of doing it.

Comment: @reirab Since when can the President amend the constitution?

Comment: @barbecue The President can't. "Elected officials" can, though, namely, Congress and the state legislatures (or just the state legislatures without Congress, if they so choose.)

Comment: @reirab It's a stretch to claim that promoting and campaigning for a constitutional amendment to implement a change is the same thing as deciding to implement the change.

Comment: @barbecue I didn't claim that. I'm not sure what you're referring to. I was responding to the claim that "any elected official doesn't get to decide post-factor who is a citizen and who isn't." In fact, there are quite a number of elected officials who can by multiple processes - but especially by constitutional amendment - do exactly that. Congress and state legislatures (or just state legislatures alone) aren't just limited to "promoting and campaigning for" constitutional amendments, but rather actually have the power to ratify them.

Comment: @reirab The way you worded your statement, it sounds like you're saying a politician can "decide" to do something by passing a constitutional amendment. My issue is that no single politician, no single group of politicians, and no single legislative body can simply "decide" to make this change. I state that that Waffle House should offer free waffles on Fridays, but it would not make sense to say I "decided" that this will happen. I can decide to lobby for free waffles, but I can't make the actual decision, which must be agreed to by many.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85213/discussion-between-barbecue-and-reirab).

Comment: I seriously doubt Trump would tweet "Ibrahim" is not a citizen.  Like you said, nothing would happen.  Instead, Trump would issue an executive order directing that federal officials are to act as if "Ibrahim" was not a citizen.  This would suck if "Ibrahim" was out of the country when that happened and wished to return.