# When are people born in the United States not "subject to its jurisdiction"?

Tags: united-states, constitution, citizenship

The 14th amendment to the US constitution begins with this text:

> 1. All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States and of the State wherein they reside.

What kinds of people (or rather, babies) are born in the USA but not subject to its jurisdiction?

Note: I'm *not* asking about the President's power with regards to this amendment, I just want to know what it refers to.

Comment: Two possibilities out of top of my head: 1) children born to diplomats; 2) children born to an invading army.

Comment: @ach: Are these out of the top of your head or out of law books / binding case law? ...

Comment: Top of my head indeed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange Network. It would be better positioned at Law.SE.

Comment: This [similar question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/33056) on Law SE pretty much covers it. Basically: kids of diplomats, kids of invading armies on occupied territory, kids of Native Americans if on a tribe's land.

Comment: Constitutional questions are on topic in both Law and Politics

Comment: @Giter but Native Americans were made citizens of the US in 1924, so the last exception no longer applies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Donald Trump revoke birthright citizenship?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34966/why-cant-donald-trump-revoke-birthright-citizenship)

Comment: @AloneProgrammer "when is not X?" isn't the same question as "why can't P change X"?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer: What phoog said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

People are not subject to the jurisdiction of the United States when they are diplomatic personnel with diplomatic immunity. Invading military forces were another exception.

This provision has been interpreted to allow someone to voluntarily renounce their citizenship (i.e. you start out with citizenship if you are born in the United States or naturalized as a citizen, but can lose that citizenship if you voluntarily renounce it), but even someone who renounces their citizenship, and is located in the United States, is "subject to the jurisdiction of the United States."

This has been settled law controlled by binding U.S. Supreme Court precedent for 120 years.

Children of non-citizens have been considered entitled to birthright citizenship in the United States under the 14th Amendment [since at least 1898](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Wong_Kim_Ark):

> United States v. Wong Kim Ark, 169 U.S. 649 (1898),[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Wong_Kim_Ark) is a United
>   States Supreme Court case in which the Court ruled 6–2 that a child
>   born in the United States, of parents of Chinese nationality who at
>   the time had a permanent domicile and residence in the United States
>   and were carrying on business there but not as employees of the
>   Chinese government, automatically became a U.S. citizen.

In this case the U.S. Supreme Court stated:

> [T]he real object of the Fourteenth Amendment of the Constitution, in
>   qualifying the words, "All persons born in the United States" by the
>   addition "and subject to the jurisdiction thereof," would appear to
>   have been to exclude, by the fewest and fittest words (besides
>   children of members of the Indian tribes, standing in a peculiar
>   relation to the National Government, unknown to the common law), **the
>   two classes of cases -- children born of alien enemies in hostile
>   occupation and children of diplomatic representatives of a foreign
>   State** -- both of which, as has already been shown, by the law of
>   England and by our own law from the time of the first settlement of
>   the English colonies in America, had been recognized exceptions to the
>   fundamental rule of citizenship by birth within the country.
>
> ...
>
> [T]he Fourteenth Amendment affirms the ancient and fundamental rule of
>   citizenship by birth within the territory, in the allegiance and under
>   the protection of the country, including all children here born of
>   resident aliens, **with the exceptions or qualifications (as old as the
>   rule itself) of children of foreign sovereigns or their ministers, or
>   born on foreign public ships, or of enemies within and during a
>   hostile occupation of part of our territory**, and with the single
>   additional exception of children of members of the Indian tribes owing
>   direct allegiance to their several tribes. The Amendment, in clear
>   words and in manifest intent, includes the children born, within the
>   territory of the United States, of all other persons, of whatever race
>   or color, domiciled within the United States.

The U.S. Supreme Court in this case also made clear that Congress does not have the power to override this Constitutional grant of birthright citizenship and this provision of the Constitution is "self-executing" and does not require implementing legislation to be effective:

> **The power of naturalization, vested in Congress by the Constitution,
>   is a power to confer citizenship, not a power to take it away.** "A
>   naturalized citizen," said Chief Justice Marshall, becomes a member of
>   the society, possessing all the rights of a native citizen, and
>   standing, in the view of the Constitution, on the footing of a native.
>   The Constitution does not authorize Congress to enlarge or abridge
>   those rights. The simple power of the National Legislature is to
>   prescribe a uniform rule of naturalization, and the exercise of this
>   power exhausts it so far as respects the individual. The Constitution
>   then takes him up, and, among other rights, extends to him the
>   capacity of suing in the courts of the United States, precisely under
>   the same circumstances under which a native might sue.
>
> Osborn v. United States Bank, 9 Wheat. 738, 827. Congress having no
>   power to abridge the rights conferred by the Constitution upon those
>   who have become naturalized citizens by virtue of acts of Congress, a
>   fortiori **No act or omission of Congress, as to providing for the
>   naturalization of parents or children of a particular race, can affect
>   citizenship acquired as a birthright, by virtue of the Constitution
>   itself, without any aid of legislation**. **The Fourteenth Amendment**,
>   while it leaves the power where it was before, in Congress, to
>   regulate naturalization, **has conferred no authority upon Congress to
>   restrict the effect of birth, declared by the Constitution to
>   constitute a sufficient and complete right to citizenship.**

It should be needless to say that an Executive Order may not alter a rule of law that the U.S. Supreme Court has clearly and consistently for 120 years held that Congress may not change.

Subsequent case law has made clear that domicile or permanent residence in the United States is not required for a child born in the United States to be a U.S. citizen.

For example, children of Canadian parents living in Canada whose mother had to be rushed to deliver their child in a U.S. hospital just across the border are [dual U.S.-Canadian citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthright_citizenship_in_the_United_States#Canadians_transferred_to_U.S._hospitals), even though they were only on temporary visitor's visas for medical purposes.

[Legal scholarship regarding the original intent](https://www.bloomberg.com/opinion/articles/2018-10-30/birthright-citizenship-puts-trump-judges-in-a-bind) of the language (even from conservative judges) supports this position:

> Law professor Gerard Magliocca, the author of the definitive biography
>   of John Bingham, the Ohio congressman who was the principal draftsman
>   of the 14th Amendment, wrote a [law review article](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=965268) years ago
>   explaining why.
>
> To simplify, the words “subject to the jurisdiction thereof” weren’t
>   intended to exclude the children of ordinary foreigners living in the
>   U.S. Such foreigners are indeed subject to U.S. jurisdiction, meaning
>   that they are obligated to follow U.S. laws and can be punished for
>   failing to do so.
>
> The words “subject to the jurisdiction thereof” were probably intended
>   to exclude the children of hostile noncitizens invading the U.S. (such
>   as some Native Americans) and the children of foreign diplomats, who
>   were entitled to some early form of diplomatic immunity.
>
> Judge James Ho, a Trump nominee to the U.S. Court of Appeals for the
>   5th Circuit and an originalist himself, made a similar point in an
>   [article](http://articles.latimes.com/2007/mar/10/opinion/oe-ho10) before he became a judge.

The debate over the adoption of the 14th Amendment [also reflects this meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthright_citizenship_in_the_United_States#Original_meaning):

> During the original debate over the 14th Amendment Senator Jacob M.
>   Howard of Michigan—the sponsor of the Citizenship Clause—described the
>   clause as having the same content, despite different wording, as the
>   earlier Civil Rights Act of 1866, namely, that it excludes American
>   Indians who maintain their tribal ties and "persons born in the United
>   States who are foreigners, aliens, who belong to the families of
>   ambassadors or foreign ministers." Others also agreed that the
>   children of ambassadors and foreign ministers were to be
>   excluded. However, concerning the children born in the United
>   States to parents who are not U.S. citizens (and not foreign
>   diplomats), three senators, including Senate Judiciary Committee
>   Chairman Lyman Trumbull, the author of the Civil Rights Act, as well
>   as President Andrew Johnson, asserted that both the Civil Rights Act
>   and the 14th Amendment would confer citizenship on them at birth, and
>   no senator offered a contrary opinion.

**Footnote On Indians Not Taxed**

The "Indians Not Taxed" clause of the 14th Amendment, by the way, became moot in 1924 when all Indians in the United States were made subject to U.S. income taxes by statute in the [Indian Citizenship Act of 1924](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Citizenship_Act). [Specifically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthright_citizenship_in_the_United_States#Canadians_transferred_to_U.S._hospitals):

> The Indian Citizenship Act of 1924 provided "That all noncitizen
>   Indians born within the territorial limits of the United States be,
>   and they are hereby, declared to be citizens of the United States".
>   This same provision (slightly reworded) is contained in present-day
>   law as section 301(b) of the Immigration and Nationality Act of 1965
>   (8 USC 1401(b)).

Comment: Indians not taxed!

Comment: The category of Indians not taxed was ended by statute in 1924. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribal_sovereignty_in_the_United_States

Comment: If someone born in the US leaves the country and renounces their US citizenship, wouldn't that count?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renunciation_of_citizenship

Comment: How about NATO troops and their dependents under the Status of Forces Agreement?

Comment: @Brythan American Indians not taxed were indeed excepted from the 14th Amendment but since 1924 American Indians born in the US are all US citizens and therefore taxed.

Comment: @Burt_Harris the question is who is a citizen at birth, not who is a citizen currently.  Anyone who has renounced citizenship is of course no longer a citizen, but the person you describe was a US citizen at birth.

Comment: @o.m. NATO forces have official acts immunity only, so their children born in the US are US citizens.  This is presumably because bearing a child is not an official act.  The same is true of officers and employees of international organizations as well as of lower-level consular and diplomatic staff.  Actually the "bearing a child" logic is facetious: the real reason a diplomat's child is not subject to US jurisdiction is that diplomatic immunity extends to the diplomat's family.  Official acts immunity of course does not.

Comment: @Burt_Harris - that's voluntarily renouncing citizenship. Not sure how that relates to an involuntary revocation of birthright citizenship.

Comment: The OP's headline question was "**When** are people born in the United States not subject to its jurisdiction?”  I'm just saying that they are no longer subject to its jurisdiction (for example income tax) after renunciation.

Comment: @Burt_Harris Not really. If someone who renounces their citizenship has children in the United States, both the parent and the child are subject to the jurisdiction of the United States, which basically means that they can be prosecuted for criminal offenses by the U.S. if they commit them. You do not need to be a U.S. citizen to be subject to the jurisdiction of the United States.

Comment: @Burt_Harris There are lots of people born in the United States who are not subject to federal income taxation. For example, people who have earned income in Puerto Rico but do not work for the federal government, or people who only earn income from municipal bonds, gifts, inheritances, life insurance proceeds, Social Security payments below a certain threshold, and other forms of non-taxable income.

Comment: @ohwilleke No argument with that.  But the question wasn't about what income is non-taxable (exemptions.)   The US is (as I understand it unique in)  claiming **universal jurisdiction** over it's citizens for tax purposes.

Comment: @Burt_Harris Lawful permanent residents of the U.S. are also subject to taxation on their global income just as U.S. citizens are. https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/frequently-asked-questions-about-international-individual-tax-matters

Comment: @ohwileke, again no argument with your facts, but a lawful permanent resident doesn't fit the parameters of the OP's question.  They asked about people born in the US.   P.S.   Your answer is much improved.   Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's start off with a [quote from Sen Jacob Howard](http://memory.loc.gov/cgi-bin/ampage?collId=llcg&fileName=073/llcg073.db&recNum=11), who authored the 14th Amendment

> This amendment which I have offered is simply declaratory of what I regard as the law of the land already, that every person born within the limits of the United States, and subject to their jurisdiction, is by virtue of natural law and national law a citizen of the United States. This will not, of course, include persons born in the United States who are foreigners, aliens, who belong to the families of ambassadors or foreign ministers accredited to the Government of the United States, but will include every other class of persons. It settles the great question of citizenship and removes all doubt as to what persons are or are not citizens of the United States. This has long been a great desideratum in the jurisprudence and legislation of this country.

So, it's clear that Howard is not including ambassadors. Let's add foreign heads of state and their entourages as well (remember, the UN did not exist back then). Why? Well, let's think about this for a second...

Let's say Theresa May (UK Prime Minister) were 30 years younger and pregnant. She needs to address the UN urgently so she travels to New York, but suffers a complication and is forced to deliver in New York. Now, technically her child is a US citizen, but it's highly unlikely such citizenship would be offered or recognized. It would be understood that the May child would be a UK citizen, and not in any way a US citizen.

The key part here is `subject to the jurisdiction thereof`. Now, if you're just some foreign national who came here for a better life, you probably don't care two flips about being subject to the jurisdiction of your old country, especially if it means your child is now a US citizen. In other words, they are implicitly agreeing to be subject to the rules and regulations of the US. For 99.9% of the people in the world, that's no big deal.

But if you're an ambassador or head of state, that matters, and it matters a *lot*. That subset is not here to be subject to our laws. Indeed, they're here under their own authority and laws. So to suggest that they are somehow subject to our laws solely by having given birth here is to run counter to everything an ambassador represents. And for them to accept that their children are now US citizens, implicitly or not, would be to create an immense conflict of interest, if for no other reason than the US could then hold said child hostage (in their interests as a US citizen) to pressure world powers to bend to their will. No nation anywhere would accept such terms.

Comment: Theresa May is not a head of state.

Comment: @phoog but she is a "foreign minister accredited to the Government of the United States" when speaking to the UN. The example works better with Elizabeth II, who gave birth twice after becoming Queen

Comment: Do you read "foreigners, aliens" to be connected to these diplomats (as in "foreigners, aliens, you know, the diplomats for example") or are those multiple exemptions. If they aren't the same, what are these "foreigners, aliens" that are also exempt?

Comment: @janh U.S. immigration law defines "alien" as anyone who isn't a national of the United States. Even non-citizen legal permanent residents are aliens.

Comment: @reirab: that's what I understand. I don't know if the definition changed, or if they are supposed to be excluded from birthright, or the diplomat-part is a further clarification on what types of "foreigner, alien" shall be excluded.

Comment: @Caleth I think she's actually not "accredited to the US" in that case, but as a head of government she would be treated the same as a head of state.  Diplomatic visitors to the UN aren't accredited to the US, but their visits are announced to the US and they enjoy similar diplomatic immunities as a result.  So yes, the US-born child of a head of government visiting the UN would count as the "child of a diplomat" for citizenship purposes.  For heads of state (and maybe of government, I don't remember), even personal visits are under diplomatic immunity, but the same is not true of ambassadors.

Comment: @janh "who are members of the family..." is a restrictive relative clause that *describes and limits* the "foreigners, aliens" to whom the exemption applies.  If it applied to all foreigners and aliens, why mention diplomats at all?  In those days, it was common to insert a comma before a relative clause.  Alternatively, "aliens" is parenthetical, restating "foreigners," and with its omission the sentence would read "persons born in the US who are foreigners who belong to the families of..." without any commas.

Comment: @janh It's not clear, really. The only clear group listed is ambassadors (for the reasons I laid out). There's a case to be made on both ends. But, in terms of how the law is applied, it's covering everyone *except* people here explicitly representing foreign powers.

Comment: "That subset is not here to be subject to our laws." The intent of the person having the child is irrelevant. It is that person's legal status, whether or not they intend to be subject to the jurisdiction of the United States that matters.

Comment: @ohwilleke isn't it the *child's* immunity from US jurisdiction, as the family member of a diplomat, that leads to the nonacquisition of US citizenship?  The *subject to the jurisdiction* clause, after all, restricts "all persons born or naturalized in the United States" directly; there is no mention of their parents.

Comment: @phoog A fair point, but I don't know if it has been definitively resolved and the immunity of a child is in any case derivative of the immunity of a parent.

Comment: @ohwilleke well it's certainly long-standing practice (whether resolved by the courts, I do not know) that official acts immunity of the parent does not trigger the 14th amendment's jurisdiction exception.  But as far as I can tell, the people who have full immunity are the same people whose immunity extends to their families, so the question I raised has no practical significance.

Comment: Even if they are not agreeing to our laws, they are still subject to them, both the requirements and the protections. Our laws don't only apply to our citizens. Anyhoo, +1, a well-formed answer.

Comment: @Machavity - Source you provided has some more on the topic (like Indians being excluded as `quasi-foreigners`), as well as `aliens and others`, so I don't think the quote means what you think it means. Additionally, the Constitution is a legal document and legal definition of jurisdiction is also different trom what I think you think it means in this case. Lastly, your interpretation would mean that a child of US citizen(s) born abroad cannot be granted US citizenship, including US diplomats, so something has to give...

Answer (score 5):

According to an op-ed [appearing in the Nov 1, 2018 Wall St. Journal by Matthew Spalding:](https://www.wsj.com/articles/the-case-against-birthright-citizenship-1541025425)

> Democrats and Republicans alike ... claim [the 14th Amendment] means anyone born in the U.S. has a constitutional right to citizenship. But a closer look at the language and history shows this is not the Constitution’s mandate and should never have become national policy.
>
> The crucial phrase is “subject to the jurisdiction thereof.” As originally understood when Congress proposed the amendment in 1866, that referred not merely to the obligation of following U.S. laws but also, and more important, to full political allegiance. According to Lyman Trumbull—who was chairman of the Senate Judiciary Committee and a co-author of the 14th Amendment—being “subject to the complete jurisdiction of the United States” meant “not owing allegiance to anybody else.”
>
> That reading is supported by the 1866 Civil Rights Act, also written by Trumbull, which Congress passed over President Andrew Johnson’s veto before proposing the 14th Amendment. The Supreme Court endorsed this reading in the Slaughter-House Cases (1872) and Elk v. Wilkins (1884).

This article, intentionally or not, implies that foreign political allegiance by a person's parents is disqualifying for birthright citizenship.  But the expression applies to the child, not the parents.  Read the entire amendment, 1st section:

> All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States and of the state wherein they reside. No state shall make or enforce any law which shall abridge the privileges or immunities of citizens of the United States; nor shall any state deprive any person of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law; nor deny to any person within its jurisdiction the equal protection of the laws.
>
> [US 14th Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/amendmentxiv)

The article by Matthew Spalding passes over this error and begins talking about illegal immigration in the example of US vs. Wong Kim Ark:

> Even when the justices expanded the constitutional mandate U.S. v. Wong Kim Ark (1898), the decision cited as establishing birthright citizenship, they held only that the children of legal permanent residents were automatically citizens. The high court has never held that the clause confers automatic citizenship on the children of temporary visitors, much less of aliens in the country illegally.
>
> [The Case Against Birthright Citizenship](https://www.wsj.com/articles/the-case-against-birthright-citizenship-1541025425)

But this idea, "aliens in the country illegally," does not appear in US vs. Wong Kim Ark.  The court's only possible criterion to residency is permanence:

> The evident intention, and the necessary effect, of the submission of this case to the decision of the court upon the facts agreed by the parties were to present for determination the single question stated at the beginning of this opinion, namely, whether a child born in the United States, of parent of Chinese descent, who, at the time of his birth, are subjects of the Emperor of China, but have a permanent domicil and residence in the United States, and are there carrying on business, and are not employed in any diplomatic or official capacity under the Emperor of China, becomes at the time of his birth a citizen of the United States. For the reasons above stated, this court is of opinion that the question must be answered in the affirmative.
>
> [US v. Wong Kim Ark](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/169/649#ZO-169_US_649astref) , p.705

...but even with this possible criterion against some people's citizenship, the opinion held that "citizenship by birth is established by the mere fact of birth under the circumstances defined in the Constitution." (p. 702)

While the supporters of Donald Trump's rhetoric about birthright citizenship have attempted to validate his claim constitutionally and through Supreme Court precedent, it appears to me that they have failed to make this case.

In addition, the opinion at US v. Wong Kim Ark assert that "The Fourteenth Amendment ... contemplates two sources of citizenship, and two only: birth and naturalization."  They go on to write:

> The power of naturalization, vested in Congress by the Constitution, is ***a power to confer citizenship, not a power to take it away.*** "A naturalized citizen," said Chief Justice Marshall, becomes a member of the society, possessing all the rights of a native citizen, and standing, in the view of the Constitution, on the footing of a native. The Constitution does not authorize Congress to enlarge or abridge those rights. The simple power of the National Legislature is to prescribe a uniform rule of naturalization, and the exercise of this power exhausts it so far as respects the individual. The Constitution then takes him up, and, among other rights, extends to him the capacity of suing in the courts of the United States, precisely under the same circumstances under which a native might sue.
>
> *Osborn v. United States Bank, 9 Wheat. 738, 827*. Congress having no power to abridge the rights conferred by the Constitution upon those who have become naturalized citizens by virtue of acts of Congress, a fortiori no act or omission of Congress, as to providing for the naturalization of parents or children of a particular race, can affect citizenship acquired as a birthright, by virtue of the Constitution itself, without any aid of legislation. The Fourteenth Amendment, while it leaves the power where it was before, in Congress, to regulate naturalization, has conferred no authority upon Congress to restrict the effect of birth, declared by the Constitution to constitute a sufficient and complete right to citizenship.
>
> [US v. Wong Kim Ark](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/169/649#ZO-169_US_649astref) p. 702-703, emphasis added

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting more explicitly that the Supreme Court's ruling's mention of Wong Kim Ark's parents' "permanent domicil and residence" does not imply that babies of those lacking permanent domicil and residence would not be citizens; it just means that they did not consider the question.  They didn't consider it because they didn't have to consider it to resolve Wong Kim Ark's case.

Comment: The article is certainly intentional in the claims it is making. Not sure why this particular professional partisan pundit's op-ed carries any particular authority on the subject, though.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, it's not about authority, it's about politics.  And politics is us, not the experts.

Comment: No, if someone is making a claim about the law and the history of the law, it's not about random partisan opinion, and certainly, on a stack exchange answer, you should be offering, as references, something with some kind of authoritative expertise. "According to an op-ed" is meaningful if you are citing a professor of American history with a scholarly publication resume, or an expert in a specific field. "Here's what a professional partisan spin merchant has to offer" tells us little when the question is asking about something that isn't just opinion.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, are you concerned that my Answer doesn't refute the partisan claims with sufficient authority?

Comment: No, I was asking you to give more preface to *why* you cited that linked op-ed. It seems like it was because that seems to encapsulate the message being offered, but with nothing other than "according to," it can easily be interpreted as something considered more authoritative than that. Sorry if I side-tracked from that message.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, I'm not too inclined to preface the article any more than I have... I think that the question of authority is imminent for this discussion, and I want my Answer to serve as a template for people in their own thinking about it.  It is too easy to be naive when people are asserting authority as they are doing today, so I want a person who reads my answer to develop their sense about this instead of offering readers a tweetable "done" line.

Comment: Fair enough. It is, ultimately, your answer, after all. If it is important to me to make certain points, I can offer my own answer. Thanks for considering and responding.